# Codeigniter extending native library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem in extending native library in codeigniter.

CONTROLLER:

```
function search(){

    $query_array = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'category' => $this->input->post('category')
    );

    $query_id = $this->input->save_query($query_array); //extends to save_query

    redirect("site/view_games/$query_id");
}
```

EXNTENDED LIBRARY:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct access allowed.');
class MY_Input extends CI_Input{

function MY_Input(){
    parent::CI_Input();

}
function save_query($query_array){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->db->insert('e_queries', array('query_string' => http_build_query($query_array)));

    return $CI->db->insert_id();
}
?>
```

CONFIGURATIONS:
my MY_Input.php in is the application/libraries/MY_Input.php

Where did I messed up? Huhuhuuh.

Comment: You need to place it inside `application/core`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **CI_Input class** is a core library . You will have to put your **MY_Input.php** file under **application/core/**

Comment: It works fine. Just a note: if you customize the class prefix in the application/config/config.php file (e.g.: using "SOME_" instead of "MY_" in the $config['subclass_prefix'] setting), the file under application/core/ must be called SOME_Input.php